# awk: non-terminated string

Tags: awk, terminal

I'm trying to run the command below, and its giving me the error. Thoughts on how to fix? I would rather have this be a one line command than a script.

```
grep  "id\": \"http://room.event.assist.com/event/room/event/" failed_events.txt |
head -n1217 |
awk -F/ ' { print $7 } ' |
awk -F\" ' { print "url \=  \"http\:\/\/room\.event\.assist\.com\/event\/room\/event\/'{ print $1 }'\?schema\=1\.3\.0\&form\=json\&pretty\=true\&token\=582EVTY78-03iBkTAf0JAhwOBx\&account\=room_event\"" } '
awk: non-terminated string url =  "ht... at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  <<< 
awk: giving up
 source line number 2
```

The line below exports out a single column of ID's:

```
grep  "id\": \"http://room.event.assist.com/event/room/event/" failed_events.txt |
    head -n1217 |
    awk -F/ ' { print $7 } '

156512145
898545774
454658748
898432413
```

I'm looking to get the ID's above into a string like so:

" url = "string...'ID'string"

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and expected output? While we can fix your syntax errors (messy quotes, it looks like), I strongly suspect there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

take a look what you have in last awk :

```
 awk -F\" 
 '  #single start here
    { print "  #double starts for print, no ends

        url \=  \"http\:\/\/room\.event\.assist\.com\/event\/room\/event\/
 '   #single ends here???

        { print $1 }'..... #single again??? ...
(rest codes)
```

and you want to print exact `{print }` out? i don't think so. why you were nesting `print` ?

Comment: @it won't work like that. anyway your question `why non-terminated string` was answered. you better take a look @ghoti's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the elements of your pipe can be expressed right inside awk.

I can't tell exactly what you want to do with the last awk script, but here are some points:

- Your "grep" is really just looking for a string of text, not a
  regexp.
- You can save time and simplify things if you use awk's
  `index()` function instead of a RE. Output formats are almost always
  best handled using printf().

Since you haven't provided your input data, I can't test this code, so you'll need to adapt it if it doesn't work.  But here goes:

```
awk -F/ '
  BEGIN {
    string="id\": \"http://room.event.assist.com/event/room/event/";
    fmt="url = http://example.com/event/room/event/%s?schema=whatever\n";
  }

  count == 1217 { nextfile; }

  index($0, string) {
    split($7, a, "\"");
    printf(fmt, a[0]);
    count++;
  }' failed_events.txt
```

If you like, you can use awk's `-v` option to pass in the `string` variable from a shell script calling this awk script.  Or if this is a stand-alone awk script (using `#!` shebang), you could refer to command line options with `ARGV`.

Comment: I was looking to do this as a single command and not a script, is it not possible?